# Brand new to CSS and cannot figure out how to properly code different classes/property values to each of my html paragraphs

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning how to use class selectors and know that once I have assigned a class to a specific paragraph within my html, my next move should be to create new rules for those classes within my CSS. I am following along the Head First HTML CSS guide book and they did not specify a clear path for this one. The task is to assign different colors to each paragraph. While the first (p class="greentea")[only one paragraph shows the desired color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLDP6.png), p.greentea {color: green;} did work the rest did not. Can someone proof read the code and let me know what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

HTML

```css
p.greentea {
  color: green;
} 
p.raspberry {
  color: blue;
} 
p.blueberry {
  color: purple;
} 
p.cranberry {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="greentea">
  <img src="../images/green.jpg">
  Chock full of vitamins and minerals, this elixir
  combines the healthful benefits of green tea with
  a twist of chamomile blossoms and ginger root.
</p>
<h2>Raspberry Ice Concentration</h2>
<p class="raspberry">
  <img src="../images/lightblue.jpg">
  Combining raspberry juice with lemon grass,
  citrus peel and rosehips, this icy drink
  will make your mind feel clear and crisp.
</p>
<h2>Blueberry Bliss Elixir</h2>
<p class="blueberry">
  <img src="../images/blue.jpg">
  Blueberries and cherry essence mixed into a base
  of elderflower herb tea will put you in a relaxed
  state of bliss in no time.
</p>
<h2>Cranberry Antioxidant Blast</h2>
<p class="cranberry">
  <img src="../images/red.jpg">
  Wake up to the flavors of cranberry and hibiscus
  in this vitamin C rich elixir.
</p>
```

Comment: I appreciate you including the code snippet, I was about to do so myself. It seems everything is working fine, have you tried saving the file and refreshing the browser?

Comment: You could also remove the `p` if you want and just use `.greentea` if you will use that color on other elements.

Comment: Thank you I will give it another go.